# Extjs 4 Designer 1.2 Tab Panel

Tags: extjs4, tabpanel

I am working with ExtJs 4.0 ( Ext Designer 1.2.0). 
I have a panel with card layout which contains a button(add tab btn) and a tab panel. Each tab contains a separate toolbar with button. Add tab btn would add Tab2 if it is closed.

I observed that when I run the application, event on 2nd tab's button can be executed but if I close the second tab and add it dynamically from add tab btn, event won't be executed.

Any suggestions??

Following is my code : (MyPanel.js)

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.ui.MyPanel',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

    me.down('button[id=addTab]').on('click',me.onAddTabClick,me);
    me.down('button[text=Second Button]').on('click',me.onSecondBtnClick,me);
    },

    onSecondBtnClick: function(){
        alert("Second Btn");
    },

    onAddTabClick: function(){

        var myTab = this.down('#myTabPanel').child('#tab2');
        if (myTab) {
            myTab.show();
        } else {
            this.down('#myTabPanel').add({
                    title    : 'Tab2',
                    activeTab: 0,
                    closable : true ,
                    id: 'tab2',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        id: 'tab2',
                        closable: true,
                        title: 'Tab 2',
                        dockedItems: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'toolbar',
                                height: 29,
                                id: 'Tab2Toolbar',
                                dock: 'top',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'Second Button'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }]  
                }).show();
        }
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that because you're using `initComponent` instead of `init`, the event is only getting applied once, when `MyPanel` is first loaded. If you use the init config instead, I believe it properly applies your events whether the button has been destroyed already or not.

In short, try removing your `initComponent` block and replacing it with this, as init is the "proper" ExtJS 4 way for setting up events:

```js
init: function (){
  this.control({
    'button[id=addTab]': {
      click: this.onAddTabClick
    },
    'button[text=Second Button]':{
      click : this.onSecondBtnClick 
    }
  });
}
```

(This code is from a controller, not specifically a panel, so while I hope it works right away, keep in mind that it may require some modification. Don't forget your comma!)